# Problems making an accurate Visual Studio scheme for Vim (vim scheme specialist needed) 

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, color-scheme

I'm trying to make an accurate Visual Studio scheme.

I set `hi function` to **blood color** (`#9A1102`) for the "CSS function" (e.g. #thisisanid).

But now the brackets with properties (id, class) in html elements also have **blood color**: (ironically the same color here in Stackoverflow). But I want them blue (`#2902FC`)

e.g.:

Sample of code:

```
  " Syntax highlighting
    hi Comment   guifg=#777777 gui=none
    hi Todo   guifg=#8f8f8f gui=none
    hi Constant  guifg=#e5786d gui=none
    hi String   guifg=#2902FC gui=none
    hi Identifier  guifg=#2902FC gui=none
    hi Function  guifg=#9A1102 gui=none
    hi Type   guifg=#EF2811 gui=none
    hi Statement  guifg=#9A1102 gui=none
    hi Keyword  guifg=#9A1102 gui=none
    hi PreProc   guifg=#2902FC gui=none
    hi Number  guifg=#2902FC gui=none
    hi Special  guifg=#2902FC gui=none

    " Bottom
    hi Question guifg=white gui=none
    hi Question ctermfg=white term=none
    hi ModeMsg guifg=white gui=none
```

Is there a way to target html brackets only or target CSS selectors only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to figure out what the specific group-name is that you want to highlight.

Many group names are linked to higher-level group-names (e.g. `vimLineComment` and `shComment` link to `Comment`).  If you change the color of `Comment`, you change the color for every group that links to it.  This is why changing `Function` above affects both CSS and HTML syntax colors.

You might want to start with a helpful mapping to display the syntax group under the cursor:

```
nmap <F2> :exec ":hi " . synIDattr(synID(line("."), col("."), 1), "name")<CR>
```

*Change `<F2>` to whatever mapping you would like to use.*

Guessing from your description above, you may want something like the following:

```
hi cssIdentifier   guifg=#9A1102 gui=none
hi htmlTag         guifg=#2902FC gui=none
```

For more information on group-names:

```
:h group-name
```