# How can I change my Vim vimrc to know when I am typing a PHP variable and match the color? 

Tags: php, vim, syntax-highlighting

When using Vim the way my color syntax is now, when I type in $ it shows yellow and when I write text it comes in white. How can I configure my vimrc to know when I am writing a PHP variable ($variable) and keep the color consistent between the $ and the words after it (variable in my example)? It is just a nuisance thing, but I hate seeing variable names with non-matching color, it drives me nuts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to consider getting this to fix your problem: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1571

Comment: Thanks, i have downloaded the php.vim file, although i do not have a .vim folder in my home directory. Is it sufficient to just create the file? ie... ~/.vim/syntax/php.vim or am i mistaken on its location? Thanks again

Comment: when i tried to move the folder it told me that there is no folder in my home directory. I'm going to browse around for it and see if i can find it.

Comment: See if you have a ~/.vimrc file. A line in that file might help you locate the syntax directory. It should be: $VIMRUNTIME/syntax, assuming $VIMRUNTIME is defined, which might be /usr/share/vim/vim72/syntax/ for all users. But a better place is still ~/.vim/syntax, which you might have to create if it is not already there. This will allow the script you downloaded to override the default script which might or might not be present in /usr/share/vim/vim72/syntax/.

Comment: I created the /home/.vim/syntax folder and moved the php.vim file there. I added the following line to my vimrc, which i found in the etc/vim folder. let $VIMRUNTIME = "/home/.vim/syntax". It does not seem to be working right. What does a basic vimrc look like? I think the one I have is changing the appearance. Thanks for all the help, i am a linux/vim rookie and i am not familiar with the file structure yet.

Comment: for some reason it adds the test syntax to anything i try to open, plus it still has different text colors of the $ and the text although it does recognize php functions. I removed the $VIMRUNTIME and it still does the same thing.

Comment: If it is using the php settings and the $ is a different color from the rest of the variable name, you might want to examine the guts of that php vim script and see if there are comments maybe pointing this out, so you can change it to what you prefer...

Comment: Thanks for all of your help Michael, thanks to your link, your help and the vim website I was able to use :echo $VIMRUNTIME, :echo $HOME and :VERSION to find everything i needed. I truly appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

There is another method for you ,if you want to display some custom color for some Class,methods, etc.

First of all, download the [php.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1571).

then, run the `Highlight` test in `Gvim`, you will get some keywords like this:

```
htmlTagN    htmlTagN
htmlBoldUnderline   htmlBoldUnderline htmlUnderlineBold
htmlBoldItalic  htmlBoldItalic htmlItalicBold
htmlBold    htmlBold
htmlBoldUnderlineItalic htmlBoldUnderlineItalic htmlBoldItalicUnderline htmlUnderlineBoldItalic htmlUnderlineItalicBold htmlItalicBoldUnderline htmlItalicUnderlineBold
htmlUnderlineItalic htmlUnderlineItalic htmlItalicUnderline
htmlUnderline   htmlUnderline
htmlItalic  htmlItalic
cssStyle    cssStyle
javaScriptCommentSkip   javaScriptCommentSkip
javaScriptParens    javaScriptParens
javaScriptValue javaScriptValue javaScriptNumber
cssDefinition   cssDefinition
cssAttributeSelector    cssAttributeSelector
cssMediaBlock   cssMediaBlock
cssFontDescriptorBlock  cssFontDescriptorBlock
cssPseudoClass  cssPseudoClass
cssSpecialCharQQ    cssSpecialCharQQ
cssSpecialCharQ cssSpecialCharQ
cssLength   cssLength
cssString   cssString
phpRegion   phpRegion
phpRegionAsp    phpRegionAsp
phpRegionSc phpRegionSc
phpIdentifierComplex    phpIdentifierComplex
phpMethodsVar   phpMethodsVar
phpLabel    phpLabel
phpFoldTry  phpFoldTry
phpFoldCatch    phpFoldCatch
NONE    NONE
phpStructureHere    phpStructureHere
phpMemberHere   phpMemberHere
phpMethodHere   phpMethodHere
phpPropertyHere phpPropertyHere
phpTernaryRegion    phpTernaryRegion
phpHereDoc  phpHereDoc
phpSpecialCharfold  phpSpecialCharfold
phpPropertyInString phpPropertyInString
phpIdentifierInString   phpIdentifierInString
phpIdentifierInStringComplex    phpIdentifierInStringComplex
phpIdentifierInStringErratic    phpIdentifierInStringErratic
phpErraticBracketRegion phpErraticBracketRegion
phpStaticUsage  phpStaticUsage
phpStaticAccess phpStaticAccess
phpStaticVariable   phpStaticVariable
phpStaticCall   phpStaticCall
phpForeachRegion    phpForeachRegion
phpForRegion    phpForRegion
phpConstructRegion  phpConstructRegion
phpSwitchConstructRegion    phpSwitchConstructRegion
phpDoBlock  phpDoBlock
phpSwitchBlock  phpSwitchBlock
phpDoWhileConstructRegion   phpDoWhileConstructRegion
phpStatementRegion  phpStatementRegion
phpCaseRegion   phpCaseRegion
phpArrayRegion  phpArrayRegion
phpArrayRegionSimple    phpArrayRegionSimple
phpArrayComma   phpArrayComma phpListComma phpPREGArrayComma
phpListRegion   phpListRegion
phpBlockRegion  phpBlockRegion
phpParentRegion phpParentRegion
phpBracketRegion    phpBracketRegion
phpFoldFunction phpFoldFunction
phpFoldClass    phpFoldClass
phpFoldInterface    phpFoldInterface
htmlRegion  htmlRegion
phpDefineClassName  phpDefineClassName
phpDefineClassImplementsName    phpDefineClassImplementsName
phpDefineClassImplementsComma   phpDefineClassImplementsComma
phpDefineClassImplementsCommentOneLine  phpDefineClassImplementsCommentOneLine
phpClassBlock   phpClassBlock
phpDefineClassBlockCommentOneline   phpDefineClassBlockCommentOneline
phpDefineInterfaceName  phpDefineInterfaceName
phpDefineFuncName   phpDefineFuncName
phpDefineFuncProto  phpDefineFuncProto
phpProtoArray   phpProtoArray
phpDefineFuncBlockCommentOneline    phpDefineFuncBlockCommentOneline
phpFuncBlock    phpFuncBlock
phpDefineMethodName phpDefineMethodName
phpTryBlock phpTryBlock
phpCatchRegion  phpCatchRegion
phpCatchBlock   phpCatchBlock
phpFoldHtmlInside   phpFoldHtmlInside
phpEchoRegion   phpEchoRegion
phpClassStart   phpClassStart
phpSyncStartOfFile  phpSyncStartOfFile
phpSyncComment  phpSyncComment
phpSyncString   phpSyncString
phpRegionSync   phpRegionSync
pregConcat  pregConcat
pregClassEscapeMainQuote    pregClassEscapeMainQuote
pregClassEscapeDouble2  pregClassEscapeDouble2
pregEscapeMainQuote pregEscapeMainQuote
phpPREGRegion   phpPREGRegion
phpPREGOpenParentMulti  phpPREGOpenParentMulti
phpPREGRegionMulti  phpPREGRegionMulti
phpPREGStringStarter    phpPREGStringStarter
phpPREGArrayRegion  phpPREGArrayRegion
phpPREGArrayOpenParent  phpPREGArrayOpenParent
pregNonSpecialEscape    pregNonSpecialEscape
```

,here it is, your can modify the keywords for your php file, add some configure in your `vimrc` like this:

```
hi        TabLine        guifg=#1C1D1F          guibg=#BFBFBF           gui=NONE
```

the '`TabLine`' can replace by the keywords. `guifg` is the `fore-color`, `guibg` is the background color,`gui` is the terminal color. you can  configure it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is:

```
hi link phpIdentifier phpVarSelector
```

You can simply add this to your `~/.vimrc` file or you can create a php-specific "after" syntax file and add it there:

```
~/.vim/after/syntax/php.vim
```

Create the directories if they do not already exist.

For future highlighting changes you can use [this mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053995/problems-making-an-accurate-visual-studio-scheme-for-vim-vim-scheme-specialist-n/3055322#3055322) to figure out what the syntax group is under the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

With this function in your .vimrc you can hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> to show the syntactic group of the word/character under the cursor:

```
function! <SID>SynStack()
    if !exists("*synstack")
        return
    endif
    echo map(synstack(line('.'), col('.')), 'synIDattr(v:val, "name")')
endfunc
nnoremap <C-p> :call <SID>SynStack()<CR>
```

With this sample PHP code:

```
$var_name = false;
```

if the cursor is on the `$` I get:

```
['phpRegion', 'phpIdentifier', 'phpVarSelector']
```

else, if the cursor is on the `n` of `name` , I get:

```
['phpRegion', 'phpIdentifier']
```

which means that I need to set both `phpIdentifier` and `phpVarSelector` to the same color in my colorscheme to have a consistant look.